# How To Solve A Sudoku Puzzle Grid Size 400*400 Using Java

Tags: java, multithreading, algorithm

I'm working on a java project to solve a Sudoku with 400*400 grid size. I've used backtracking recursion to solve it but it's not giving me the solution for the complexity. I'm wondering if there is any other algorithm to work on for this type of Sudoku grid. Please help.

Comment: https://bob-carpenter.github.io/games/sudoku/java_sudoku.html

Comment: Tried doing that "search engine" thing? Like. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36037919/heuristic-function-for-applying-a-sudoku  or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudoku_solving_algorithms

Comment: Sudoku is NP-complete. You cannot have an absolutely certain solution in reasonable time, but you can try to look for heuristic solutions.

Comment: please read  [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Show what you have done up to now and where the problems are.

Answer (score 0):

As @RealSkeptic pointed out in a comment. Sudoku is NP-Complete. This means that an instance can be checked within a polynomial bound, dependent on the input size, on time. Since you tagged your question with multithreading I am proposing the following decomposition.

1. Generate appropriate candidate solutions
2. Check each candidate

Two can be done fast for all intents and purposes. One is the challenge.

I would try some form of [constaint programming][1] to reduce the number of options each cell can have. Then hash out processes to try each situation, basically parallel backtracking.

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_programming